# How to use cp to copy only certain sub-folders? [ Android - root ]

Tags: android, unix, cp

Note: I need to use this directly in a one-line command, so *no script* allowed! (I need it to create a temporary directory for my android app for rooted devices)

```
String cmd = "su | [ copy cmd here ] | chmod 777 data/ztemp";
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Basically I want to copy the sared_prefs files, but I need to keep them in their original app folder.

This is the original structure

```
data
 |-data
    |-app1
    |  |-shared_prefs
    |  |    |-files
    |  |    
    |  |-folder1
    |  +-folder2
    |
    |-app2
       |-shared_prefs
       |    |-files
       |    
       |-folder1
       +-folder2
```

and I would like to copy it like this

```
data
 |-ztemp
    |-app1
    |  +-shared_prefs
    |       |-files
    |
    |-app2
       +-shared_prefs
            |-files
```

I've tried `cp data/*/shared_prefs/* ztemp/` but I've lost the  folders.

The result of the previous:

```
data
 |-ztemp
    |-files
    |-files
    |-...
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: I've put the android tag because I'm not sure about specific flags of the platform or stuff like that :)

Comment: You should use -r or -R to copy folders recursively in Linux.

Comment: Yep, I know, but how to skip the unneeded folders? They're pretty heavy sometimes (usually they're caching folders) and I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a script to handle this (I don't think there's a one-line command to do it)

So basically I created this sh

```
<!-- language: lang-sh -->
#!/bin/sh
DATA=/data/data
TEMP=/data/ztemp;

if [ ! -e ${TEMP} ]
then
        mkdir ${TEMP}
fi

for f in ${DATA}/*;
do
        PACKAGE="$(basename "$f")"
        if [ -e ${DATA}/${PACKAGE}/shared_prefs ]
        then
                if [ ! -e ${TEMP}/${PACKAGE} ]
                then
                        mkdir ${TEMP}/${PACKAGE}
                fi
                cp -r ${DATA}/${PACKAGE}/shared_prefs/* ${TEMP}/${PACKAGE}
        fi
done

echo Finished!
```

copied inside the device

```
private static void copyScript(Context context) {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(SCRIPT);
        String content = convertStreamToString(is);
        fos = context.openFileOutput(SCRIPT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and run

```
rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "su | chmod 777 " + SCRIPT_FOLDER + SCRIPT
                + " | sh " + SCRIPT_FOLDER + SCRIPT
                + " | chmod 777 " + SCRIPT_FOLDER + SCRIPT
                + " | chmod -R 777 " + TEMP
        );
```

Not really nice, but it's the only solution I've found (for now).